# Prism Event Aggregator Not Working With Async/Await

Tags: prism

I am working with prism in a client server app with sql server. I have a loading screen after login screen in which I've fetch the main data in async task for main windows and publish it and subscribe in main windows like customers, Users and etc. But the problem is that subscriber not updated. But If I sign out and sign in again then subscriber updated.
Subscriber not updated first time.
Here is the code of loading screen

```
public class StartPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    private List<Models.User> Users { get; set; }
    private List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public List<Tax> Taxes { get; set; }
    private Models.User _user;
    private object _userId;

    public StartPageViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, Models.User user,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _user = user;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        Customers = new List<Customer>();
        Users = new List<Models.User>();
        Invoices = new List<Invoice>();
        Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
        Taxes = new List<Tax>();
    }
    [OnCommand("InitializeStartPage")]
    public async void InitializeStartPage()
    {
        if (!InternetCs.IsConnectedToInternet())
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ShellRegion, "InternetConnection");
        else
        {
           await Task.WhenAll(CheckUser(), Preloading()).ContinueWith(async(t, _) =>
           {
               _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AllCustomersEvent>().Publish(Customers);
               _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AllInvoicesEvent>().Publish(Invoices);
               _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CurrentUserEvent>().Publish(_user);
               _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AllUsersEvent>().Publish(Users);
               _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AllVehiclesEvent>().Publish(Vehicles);
               _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AllTaxesEvent>().Publish(Taxes);

               if (_user != null && _user.Status)
               {
                   _user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
                   _user.LoginStatus = true;
                   _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Update(_user);
                   await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
                   _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, "Home");
                   _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ShellRegion, "MainWindow");
               }
               else
               {
                   _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ShellRegion, "LoginWindow");
               }
           }, null, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());                
        }
    }

    private async  Task<Models.User> CheckUser()
    {
        IsoStorage.Instance.TryGetValue("UserId", out _userId);
        _user = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetAsync((int)_userId);
        return _user;
    }

    private async Task Preloading()
    {
        Customers = await _unitOfWork.CustomerRepository.GetAsync();
        Invoices = await _unitOfWork.InvoiceRepository.GetAsync();
        Users = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetAsync();
        Vehicles = await _unitOfWork.VehicleRepository.GetAsync();
        Taxes = await _unitOfWork.TaxRepository.GetAsync();
    }
}
```

and here is example subscriber

```
public AdminProfileViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        Users = new List<Models.User>();
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<AllUsersEvent>().Subscribe(AdminAllUsers, ThreadOption.PublisherThread);
    }

    private void AdminAllUsers(List<Models.User> obj)
    {
        Users = obj;
    }
```

Comment: Event aggregator not properly working with async/await task

Comment: I just Update My Code But it is still not working. Now there is not Async Task

Comment: `public async void InitializeStartPage()
        {
            if (!InternetCs.IsConnectedToInternet())
                _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ShellRegion, "InternetConnection");
            else
            {
                Users = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get();
                _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AllUsersEvent>().Publish(Users);
                _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, "Home");
                _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ShellRegion, "MainWindow");              
            }
        }}`

Comment: Make sure your objects that are subscribing have been created first.

Comment: You mean register subscribers first then register publisher when registering views? @BrianLagunas